# How do I create my own terrain and 3d print

Tags: modeling

I want to hand sculpt my terrain and not get it from google maps.But I want it to print on a 3D printer

Comment: Welcome to Blender stack exchange. Can you explain what it is you have done so far and what problems you have encountered?

Comment: I have subdivided a plane and have changed its shape using modelling tools and have made a terrain.i then exported that file as a Stl to cura.but when I want it to print the model it only predicts slices a little bit

Comment: Did you have a look at the blender manual regarding 3D printing? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/mesh_analysis.html?highlight=printing and also this infor for Blender 2.7x https://daler.github.io/blender-for-3d-printing/printing/index.html